# How do I set a cookie in a Rack::MockRequest?

Tags: ruby, rack

I want to set a cookie when making a request with `Rack::MockRequest`

```
cookie = "_session_id=123"
client = Rack::MockRequest.new(@app)

#something like this?
response = client.get("/", "Cookie" => cookie)
```

How do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
response = client.get('/', "HTTP_COOKIE" => cookie)
```

Comment: thanks! can you also answer this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23603133/how-to-i-specify-that-the-protocol-is-https-in-a-rackmockrequest