# How to I specify that the protocol is https in a Rack::MockRequest?

Tags: ruby, rack

I want to set the protocol to https when making a request with Rack::MockRequest

```
client = Rack::MockRequest.new(@app)

#something like this?
env = @app.env.merge("rack.url_scheme" => "https")
response = client.get("/", env)
```

How do I do it?

[Here are the Rack docs.](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/SPEC.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
response = client.get("/", "rack.url_scheme" => "https")
```

should work